# jQuery tables and json

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, mongodb

1. I'm trying to create a table in jQuery that will keep the same
   jQuery style I already have in my web site.

   The table :

   ```
   <table  id = "jobsTable"  data-role="table" >
   ```

   And its creating a table that doesn't have  jQuery in.
2. I want part of my JSON  to add as `<tr>` , here is the JSON ( from
   mongoDB sent by Ajax response) :

   ```
    { _id: 53f8c48ddc1f5f0419f2ed53,
     bName: 'Microsoft',
     phone: 35588319,
     Email: 'microsoft@gmail.com',
     field: 'QA',
     exp: '0-2'}
   ```

lets say I want to add to that table : bNmae, phone, Email, field, exp.
Page main that include table :

```
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">

        <label for="basic">JOBS</label>
        <table  id = "jobsTable"  data-role="table" >
        <thead> 
        <tr>
            <th>Company Name</th>
            <th>Email</th> 
            <th>Contact Number</th>
            <th>Field</th>
            <th>Expirence </th>
        </tr>
        </thead> 
        <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td>microsoft</td>
            <td>microsoft@gmail.com</td> 
            <td>0508-558310</td>
            <td>QA</td>
            <td>0-2</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
```

and the javascript-ajax code :

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'JSON',
      url:'http://localhost:3000/find',
      data: workerInfo, 
      success: function(jobs){
          // 1)insert each response data into table -


      }
    });
```

Comment: It's not too clear what exactly you are asking here. Could you please try to re-word your post? Perhaps include some code that you have so that we can understand exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Its pretty simple : 1) Table that will match jquery current style. 2)Add part of json string as a row .

Comment: Add js code and the jquery page .

Comment: Take a look at the [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) function in jQuery - I think that is what you are looking for.

Comment: yes but u didnt answer how to separate json data to parts i need . then i can use append().

Comment: You need me to tell you how to loop over an object?

Comment: You mean how to loop (each) array element in the object?


$.each(json, function(idx, obj) {
 alert(obj.tagName);
});

Comment: basically yes. and add that part to <tr> and each key:value to <td> .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Make jobs an array of objects and try this:**

```
var jobs = [{
  _id: '53f8c48ddc1f5f0419f2ed53',
  bName: 'Microsoft',
  phone: '35588319',
  Email: 'microsoft@gmail.com',
  field: 'QA',
  exp: '0-2'
}];

function newJob(jobs){
    for(var i=0; i<jobs.length; i++){
        $('tbody').append('<tr><td>'+jobs[i].bName+'</td><td>'+jobs[i].Email+'</td><td>'+jobs[i].phone+'</td><td>'+jobs[i].field+'</td><td>'+jobs[i].exp+'</td></tr>');
    }  
}
newJob(jobs)
```

**Take the table rows out of your HTML**

```
<table  id = "jobsTable"  data-role="table" >
  <thead> 
    <tr>
      <th>Company Name</th>
      <th>Email</th> 
      <th>Contact Number</th>
      <th>Field</th>
      <th>Expirence </th>
    </tr>
  </thead> 
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

**So, for the AJAX request, use:**

```
function newJobs(jobs){
    for(var i=0; i<jobs.length; i++){
        $('tbody').append('<tr><td>'+jobs[i].bName+'</td><td>'+jobs[i].Email+'</td><td>'+jobs[i].phone+'</td><td>'+jobs[i].field+'</td><td>'+jobs[i].exp+'</td></tr>');
    }  
}
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    url:'http://localhost:3000/find',
    data: workerInfo, 
    success: function(jobs){
        newJob(jobs);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank u! on the newJob function : $('tbody').append .... needs to be  $('jobsTable').append ... right?

Comment: It needs to be $('tbody') to append the rows to the table body, as this is where they are in your example. It will create a new row for each job object in your JSON. I've done a jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/hf0qyLw3/

Comment: I have no idea why the table doesnt shown on my website . http://jsfiddle.net/hf0qyLw3/

Comment: I think you'll need to update it and post the link again - it's the same one which I posted

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hf0qyLw3/1/  - after update and post , the table should be : find a jon - > go button - > int this page after the jobs title

Comment: any ideas ? i checked the response by http headers - its OK.

Comment: The ajax requests won't work from jsfiddle as they're pointing to `localhost:3000` - the requests are denied (check developer tools in your browser)

Comment: It's caused by your jquery mobile CSS which sets `display: none` for the table for some reason

Comment: And how do i change that ?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know anything about jquery mobile; you may need to check their documentation. I expect that this will appear differently in a proper browser window (as opposed to the small JSFiddle results window).